# JS to add form fields with a button

Tags: javascript, php

How I create a do...while loop (or if there is a better way to go about this - please advise) for a form with potentially additional information?

Background - I've got a form that will accept a users assessment of a particular location (such as a basement). Using only 1 location per form, this works nicely and submits to my db without a problem.

Now I want to enhance this form with a "add new location" button. I don't (obviously) want to create new pages but rather a loop that can store the first location, save it (which I know could be done with be a session variable) and then clear the fields for locations 2, 3, 4, etc.

My confusion is around the functionality of the button. What type of button is this? Reset with a unique id such as `new_loc[]`?

And then when I write this as a do...while loop should I do it like this:

```
<?php
do {
    all my form fields
} while (some condition that looks for the button submit);
?>
```

ok so I have a created a simple JS that can "handle" this.

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(locInformation){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " locations");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><br><input type='text' name='location[]'>";
          document.getElementById(locInformation).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

Now the problem is that JS will add 1 new field - any suggestions on how to add a massive block of HTML to the JS? I tried adding all my fields to the JS and I get a whole bunch of unclosed string errors.

Comment: php can't "add" to a form without the original form being submitted to the server, so php can rebuild the page with any user-entered data still in the form. You need JS to add fields to a table without any kind of server involvement.

Comment: Ok so that makes sense as to why this isn't working. let me try JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've figured this out. Thanks to Marc B for suggesting JS.

**HTML for the button**

```
<input style="margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Additional Location"  onClick="addInput('locInformation');">
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(locInformation){
         if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<h3>Location " + (counter + 1) + "</h3>" + document.getElementById('additionalLoc').innerHTML;
          document.getElementById(locInformation).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

And then lastly is the new `locInformation` stuff:

```
<div id="additionalLoc" language="text">
huge block of HTML with additional fields
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all your form must have `action="" method="post"`
then add this php to your page:

```
    session_start();
           if (isset ($_POST['NameOfSubmitButtonInsideForm'])) {
               if (!isset ($_SESSION['sessionName'])) {
                  $_SESSION['sessionName'] = 1
               }
               for ($i = 0; $i <= $_SESSION['sessionName']; $i++) {
                   echo 'some html code like a form with a input that has 
                         <input type="submit" name="submit- . $i .'EndInputTag>';
               };
            }
```

So this will loop the number of times the user clicked the button and you can echo out html code based on that number, or what ever it is you need to do in the loop.